# Eclipse Commit Error svn: E204900: Can't make directory

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: E204900: Commit failed (details follow):

svn: E204900: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E204900: Can't make directory '/opt/bitnami/subversion/repos/x/dav/activities.d': Permission denied
svn: E175002: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/!svn/act/36d4274a-7c01-0010-82e2-67d061997a37': 500 Internal Server Error (https://xxxsystems.com)
```

Getting this error when try to commit from eclipse. No issue commit from tortoise.

Anything else can be done from client site? or any setting skip creating that folder or writing to that folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be multiple causes for your problem. From the error it looks like there is a SVN server on a Linux machine. The user that you use to connect to the SVN server should be located somewhere in a **authz** file located on that machine. Since you could commit from Turtoise, it means that you have all the write rules required in authz file, otherwise you would get a **forbidden** error.

**Permission denied** suggests that the user that is reading this file and serves the web requests (maybe a user that runs Apache httpd) does not have sufficient privileges to create directories. If you have access to the server, you could try to **chmod 777 -R** the root directory of the authz file or the /svn directory and restart the server. If you are on Ubuntu, you need to give ownership and write permission to web server by running **sudo chown -R root:www-data /svn** and **sudo chmod -R 775 /svn**.

One other possible cause could be Selinux, that sometimes messes with directory access if server is on CentOS, you can try to deactivate it.

If this also doesn't work, you can try a workaround on client side. If you can commit from Turtoise, then you can either find a TurtoiseSVN plugin for your version of Eclipse (saw on marketplace that there is a **ContextQuickie** plugin that might do the trick) or check at commit window if Eclipse tries to commit weird/unwanted files.

Comment: You should *never* use `chmod 777 `. Depending on how it is configured, it should be enough to authenticate the owner (`chmod 700`), if all access is made by the same user (for example, by Apache). Otherwise, allow the owner and the group (`chmod 770`).